# How to decode file pkm10 -> png

Tags: png, decode

Like the title, But I already find some tool on github
[pkm2png](https://github.com/zhukunqian/pkm2png)

Tool works well, but the file keep missing alpha.
[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgthr.png)

[image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtdHy.png)

Is there any way to fix that missing?

File pkm10: [File Pkm10](https://pixeldrain.com/u/axBctkce)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881621/1180620

Comment: It little different than my file above.

Comment: The format of your linked pkm10 file is described exactly at that link. You have a 16-byte PKM10 header saying that the image is 256x256, followed by 65536 pixel values. That's all there is to it.